# Importing data from Excel to vector in R

Tags: r, excel, csv

I am a novice in R and I have been having some trouble trying to get R and Excel to cooperate. 
I have written a code that makes it able to compare two vectors with each other and determine the differences between them:

```
data.x<-read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)

data.y<-read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)

newdata.x<-grep("DAG36|G379",data.x,value=TRUE,invert=TRUE)

newdata.x

newdata.y<-grep("DAG36|G379",data.y,value=TRUE,invert=TRUE)

newdata.y

setdiff(newdata.x,newdata.y)

setdiff(newdata.y,newdata.x)
```

The data I want to transfer from Excel to R is a long row of numbers placed as so:
“312334-2056”, “457689-0932”, “857384-9857”,….,

There are about 350 of these numbers placed in their own separate cell along a single row.

I used the command: = """" & A1 & """"  To put double quotes around every number in order for R to read it properly.

At first I tried to simply copy/paste the data directly into a vector in R, but it's as if R won’t read it as a single row of data and therefore splits it up. 
I also tried to save the excel file as a CSV file but that didn’t work either.

Lastly I tried to open it directly in to R using the command:

```
data.x<- read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)
```

But as I type in: data.x and press enter it simply says:

```
<0 rows> (or 0-lenghts row.names)
```

I simply can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show a few rows of your input data?

Comment: In R, rows usually correspond to observations and columns to variables. transpose your data in Excel and you should be fine.

Comment: You might also try reading your Excel files by installing/using the package `xlsx`, e.g. via `read.xlsx2(file, sheetIndex = 1, header=TRUE, colClasses="character")`. The package has many dependencies and reading is much slower than, e.g., with `read.csv()`, however, in some cases handling files in the format xls/xslx might work better.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to access without a reproducible example, but you should be able to transpose the Excel file into a single column.  Then import using read_csv from the readr package.  Take a look at the tidyverse package, which will contain some great tools to import and work with this type of data.

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/. It makes it easy to maintain formatting from excel into type safe tibbles.

If you can share some sample data a working solution can be generated.